# How do I search for multiple strings in any order across multiple lines?

Tags: search, grep, file-search

I'm working in a large codebase and want to see where particular strings like "foo" and "bar" are used, within *n* lines of each other, in any file in that codebase.

Ideally I'd use a built-in Unix command, but a Python script would be ok too. (Perl or Ruby would not be great).

Comment: Can you maybe give an example?

Comment: Python Script, FTW!

Answer (score 0):

Looking for `foo` and `bar` within 5 lines of each other:

```
grep -C5 foo inputfile | grep bar > outputfile
```

Add copying for 'large code base':

```
find /my/codebase/path -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -C5 foo | grep bar > outputfile
```

Comment: Doing as you have "grep -C5 foo inputfile | grep bar > outputfile"  will ultimately only display/show lines with bar. How about adding -C5 between grep and bar. So | grep -C5 bar that probably works better than your version.

Comment: Yeah, worksish with barlop's addition...but still not exactly what one would want.